# How do you do continous deployment in an AJAX application with lots of client side interaction and local data?

Tags: deployment

We have an app that is written in PHP. The front end uses javascript heavily. Generally, for normal applications that require page reloads, continuous deployment is not really an issue, because:

- The app can be deployed with build tags: `myapp-4-3-2013-b1`, `myapp-4-3-2013-b2`, etc.
- When the user loads a page (we are using the front controller pattern), we can inject the buildtag and the files are loaded from the app directory with the correct build tag.
- We do not need to keep the older builds around for too long because as the older requests finish, they will move to the newer build tags.
- The issue with database and user data being incompatible is not very high as we move people to the newer builds after their requests finish (more on this later).

Now, the problem with our app is that it uses AJAX heavily for smooth page loads. In addition, because there is no page refresh at all when people navigate through the application, people can keep their unsaved data in a their current browser session and revisit it as long as the browser has not been refreshed.

This leads to bigger problems if we want to achieve continuous deployment:

- We can keep the user's buildtag in their session (set when they make the first request) and only switch to newer buildtags after the logout and login again. This is obviously bad, because if things like the database schema changes or the format of files to be written to disk changes in a newer build, there is no way to reconcile this.
- We force all new requests to a newer build tag, but there is a possibility we change client side javascript and will break a lot of things if we force everyone with a session onto the new build tags immediately.

Obviously, the above won't occur with every build we push and hopefully will not happen a lot, but we want to build a fool proof process so that every build which passes our tests can be deployed. At the same time, we want to make sure that every deployed and test passing build does not inadvertently break in clients with running sessions cause a whole bunch of problems.

I have done some investigation and what google does (at least in google groups) is that they push a message out to the clients to refresh the application (browser window). However, in their case, all unsaved client side data (like unsaved message, etc) would be lost.

Given that applications that uses AJAX and local data are very common these days, what are some more intelligent ways of handling this that will provide minimal disruption to users/clients?

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface this that I haven't ever thought of continuous deployment before reading your post, but it does sound like quite a good idea! I've got a few examples where this would be nice.

My thoughts on solving your problem though would be to go for your first suggestion (which is cleaner), and get around the database schema changes like this:

Implement an API service layer in your application that handles the database or file access, which is outside of your build tag environment. For example, you'd have `myapp-4-3-2013-b1`, and `db-services` folders.

`db-services` would provide any interaction with the database with a series of versioned services. For example, `registerNewUser2()` or `processOrder3()`.

When you needed to change the database schema, you'd provide a new version of that service and upgrade your build tag environment to look at the new version. You'd also provide a legacy service that handles the old schema to new schema upgrade.

For example, say you registered new users like this:

```
registerNewUser2(username, password, fullname) {
    writeToDB(username, password, fullname);
}
```

And you needed to update the schema to add the user's date of birth:

```
registerNewUser3(username, password, fullname, dateofbirth) {
    writeToDB(username, password, fullname, dateofbirth);
}

registerNewUser2(username, password, fullname) {
    registerNewUser3(username, password, fullname, NULL);
}
```

The new build tag will be changed to call `registerNewUser3()`, while the previous build tag is still using `registerNewUser2()`.

So the old build tag will continue to work, just that any new users registered will have a NULL date of birth. When an updated build tag is used, the date of birth is written to the database correctly.

You would need to update `db-services` immediately, as soon as you roll out the new build tag - or even before you roll out the build tag I guess.

Once you're sure that everyone is using the new version, you can just delete `registerNewUser2()` from the next version of `db-services`.

This will be quite complicated to make sure that you are correctly handling the conversion between old API and new API calls, but might be feasible if you're already handling continuous deployment.